# Android Studio BLE - fill text field with cached value of characteristic

Tags: android-studio-3.0

New to Android Studio - this may be simple but I've searched high and low and can't seem to get this to work.

I have an android app that I inherited. It works but it is counting on the BLE device to send an update every 10 seconds to populate the text fields in the Activity.
When you switch to another activity (which has some of the same values as the other activity), you have to wait for 10 seconds or so for the text fields to populate.

From what I understand, Android knows what the values of the characteristics are (cached values) without having to ask the BLE device to update the values. I want the text fields to be populated with those cached values when the Activity starts instead of waiting for the BLE update to populate.

The app is set up with BluetoothLeService.java already and uses intents to send updated data to the Activities. I don't want to have the BLE device sending out the same data all the time just to populate the text fields. I want it to send data when a characteristic changes. The app already updates automatically when the BLE device characteristic changes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No Android internally does not keep a list of the latest characteristic values. When you get a read response or a notification the new value is sent to your app process which in Android's SDK puts the value inside your characteristic objects and then emits the callback that there is a new value.

You need to find a good way to structure your app for example so that you can reach your BLE code from both Activities. Or that your BLE code can reach out to both Activities.